# Valid hardware platforms of Vuforia/Unity applications

Tags: augmented-reality, vuforia

I have a question about Vuforia supported platforms. My interest is in running a Unity application with Vuforia on a Windows PC using a webcam as the video source. My questions are as follows:

1). Firstly, is this possible? I know there is a supported device list but this is highly biased towards mobile devices like phones and tablets. There is quoted support for Windows platforms but these all seem to be MS Surface Pros. Is there any reason why this would not work on a desktop PC running Windows?

2). What facilities of the host hardware device are being used by Vuforia and hence are required? Is it just the camera or are internal gyros and accelerometers a requirement too?

Thanks for any pointers,
Dave

Have tried googling, but can't find any online references to this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Vuforia does not support Win32 as a platform, however Windows UWP is supported, see here https://library.vuforia.com/getting-started/getting-started-vuforia-engine-windows-10-development. If your webcam shows up in UWP Media Capture API then it should work with Vuforia as any other system camera on Windows tablets. Note that this might not work if the laptop/PC already has a built-in camera and you want to use an external USB camera. In this case a possible fix is to disable the built-in camera in the Device Manager.

If this does not work it is possible to pass image frames to Vuforia by implementing a Vuforia Driver https://library.vuforia.com/platform-support/creating-custom-driver, however this requires significantly more effort.

Regarding hardware requirements. Several Vuforia features work with just image data (Image Targets, Model Targets, etc.). However some (like Area Targets) require a working device tracker which is either provided by the platform (ARKit, ARCore) or requires a calibrated Camera-IMU pair (https://library.vuforia.com/environments/vuforia-fusion). Again, in Vuforia Driver you can also pass tracking data from an external device tracker, however this would also require significant amount of effort and it is unlikely you can get something to work just out of webcam data as typically most device trackers use a combination of Camera and IMU data to reach reasonable levels of accuracy and robustness.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Yes, I appreciate that most AR experiences would ideally need a mix of visual/optical and IMU data fused together. My frustration is that if I am basically creating my own system hardware (as opposed to using an off the shelf device, like an iPad), then integrating Vuforia capability is challenging even if I have a camera and IMU onboard. Do you know whether it is possible to use Vuforia in conjunction with Unity and run it on a Windows platform?

Comment: I believe I answered above... in summary yes, creating a UWP app (see the first link).